# Make response of multiple files in flask

Tags: python, flask

Use [`send_file()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file) or [`send_from_directory()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory) can make a valid response of a single file object in flask.
But is it possible to make a response of multiple files in flask?
It seems that this kind of custom response should be converted to json type, if so, how to "jsonify" it?

Comment: I don't believe there's way you can respond with multiple files in HTTP protocol. However, there's a work-around that you can use `tar` or `zip` to pack/compress multiple files (even folders) into a single file, and you can respond with the single packed/compressed file.

Answer (score 0):

We can use JavaScript as shown [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server) to download files. By combining this with HTML, we can create an html template that will download files and then close the window.

```js
//download.js
function urlToBase64(url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'blob';
        request.onload = function() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        };
        request.send();
    });
}

function download(filename, data){
      //For data, we need a base64 data url
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute("href", data);
    a.setAttribute("download", filename);

    a.hidden = true;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}

for (file of document.querySelectorAll('.download')){
    download(file.filename, file.url);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <div class="download" filename="file1.txt" url="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,hello%20world"></div>
    <div class="download" filename="file2.txt" url="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,this%20is%20another%20text%20file"></div>
    <script src="download.js"><script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

This code snippet takes a `div` element and uses it's `filename` and `url` properties to download a file. (The snippet does not work due to Stackoverflow preventing it from downloading files.)